# How to write multidimensional NumPy array to disk the same as struct.pack?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a routine that iteratively appends a 41x55 numpy array to an output file like the following:

```
fmt = 'ihhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh'
for x in range(0, 41):
    vmdata_file.write(struct.pack(fmt, *building_vms[x,:]))
```

I'm trying to replace this with a call to the ndarray.tofile method but can't get the exact same output:

```
building_vms.tofile(vmdata_file)
```

My understanding is that the tofile method writes binary data the same as that struct.pack method as long as the underlying data types in the array are the same.  How can I ensure that the tofile method writes the same binary format as the struct.pack method?

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first build the array in memory exactly how you like to have it on disk:

```
import numpy as np

firstcol = building_vms[:,0].astype('i').view('h').reshape(len(building_vms), -1)
tmp = np.hstack((firstcol , building_vms[:,1:].astype('h')))
tmp.tofile(vmdata_file)
```

Maybe slightly hackish, but instead of `.view('h').reshape(len(building_vms), -1)` you could also use `.view('2h')`.